# Get only date from datetime sql without converting to varchar so that I can sort it in excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, t-sql

Currently sql returns the date as 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000.
I want only the date part in mm/dd/yyyy format so that when I export it to excel I can still sort based on ascending or descending order.
I tried varchar but it doesnt get sorted in excel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert to `DATE`, but Excel might display those as numbers, not sure.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, col) FROM dbo.table;
```

Otherwise you can use a specific style, e.g.

```
-- yyyy-mm-dd - standard, unambiguous format
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), col, 120) FROM dbo.table;
```

Or

```
-- mm/dd/yyyy - ambiguous, regional format
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), col, 101) FROM dbo.table;
```

Comment: @user1733271 yes, is your comment just a confirmation, or is this a problem?

Comment: If I use CHAR, it wont let me sort based on date in excel

Comment: So in Excel you highlight the column and tell it that this is a date.

Comment: I want it in mm/dd/yyyy form

Comment: And you think mm/dd/yyyy is magically going to sort by date if you don't also tell Excel this is a date? With mm/dd/yyyy it is likely still going to sort as a string, does it make sense to have Jan 2012, then Jan 2013, then Feb 2012, then Feb 2013?

Answer (score 5):

To format as `mm/dd/yyyy`, convert to `VARCHAR` using format 101;

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101);

> 08/01/2013
```

[An SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6108).

Answer (score 4):

Try using `CAST` to Date:

```
SELECT Cast('2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For dd/mm/yyyy format
use 103
i.e.
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COL_Name, 103);

> 24/08/2016