# How to get only date part from a datetime column in SQL Server and without 0s

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in SQL Server.

It looks like `2015-04-16 00:13:00.000`.

I would like to get only the date component: `2015-05-01`

I tried applying the cast as follows

```
update dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
set START_DATE = CAST(START_DATE AS DATE) 
from dbo.MyTableDateOnly
```

But I get as follows, and this bothers me because when I copy to Excel, I only see the zeros. What I want to see is the date part, as mentioned above.

```
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

Also, is there a way, to split the date component, into the year, month and day columns, in sql?

EDIT : I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. To get individual columns for YEAR, MONTH and DAY, I tried this based on some of the replies. But I get an error

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
ADD ADMIT_YEAR varchar(100)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
ADD ADMIT_MONTH varchar(100)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
ADD ADMIT_DAY varchar(100)

UPDATE dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
SET ADMIT_YEAR = (SELECT DATEPART(year, START_DATE) 
                  FROM dbo.MyTableDateOnly)
```

I get the error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: can be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999682/get-only-date-from-datetime-sql-without-converting-to-varchar-so-that-i-can-sort

Comment: When you store a datetime in a column, it doesn't matter how you format it before inserting it, it will still be a datatime

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the date, then store just the date?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableDateOnly ALTER COLUMN START_DATE DATE;
```

That way you won't have to `CAST` updates to a date (that will have no effect), or `CAST` to a `DATE` every time you select from the table.

For the second part of your question, there is no need to `SELECT` as otherwise you are returning every single `START_DATE` in the table, per row updated:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTableDateOnly SET ADMIT_YEAR = DATEPART(year, START_DATE );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the MySql and SQL Server tags, they dont't work the same way.
I'll talk about SQL Server, where you can use the DATEPART instruction

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, 01-12-2016), DATEPART(month, 01-12-2016), DATEPART(day, 01-12-2016);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: I tried doing this, but couldn't get it to work. Please have a look

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableDateOnly 
ADD START_YEAR varchar(100)

update dbo.MyTableDateOnly set ADMIT_YEAR = (SELECT DATEPART(year, START_DATE) from dbo.MyTableDateOnly )

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE won't work as the base datatype is DateTIMe.
i.e START_DATE datatype is DATETIME. So while selecting the data I mean in select query you can use as you want. For converting it so many methods available. The below one in your case

```
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change structure, instead query formatted values, like:

```
select left(convert(nvarchar(10), start_date, 120), 10)
```